# Agenda which is added to the calendar is fine with Week view but in month view it is coming one day earlier in US

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar to publish an agenda. In full calendar in week view it is displaying the added agenda perfectly but when i am trying to see it in month view it is displaying the added one day before when the agenda has been added.
This issue is coming in US time zone only, when i am trying to open it in INDIA the both view are working perfectly fine.

On calendar we are displaying it with

```
if (event.vanNumb != undefined) {
                element.find('.fc-title').text('');
                if(event.van == true){

                   var jsDate = new Date(event.start);
                   var today = moment(presentDate);
                   var daysDiff =daysDifference(moment(event.start),today);
                   year    = jsDate.getFullYear ();
                   month   = jsDate.getMonth ();
                   day     = jsDate.getDate ();
                   month      += 1;
                   month   = ("0" + month).slice (-2);
                   day     = ("0" + day)  .slice (-2);

                   if(daysDiff ==0){
                       jQuery('.fc-month-view [data-date="'+year +'-'+ month +'-'+ day+'"]').addClass('fc-today-in-transit');
                   }else{
                       jQuery('.fc-month-view [data-date="'+year +'-'+ month +'-'+ day+'"]').addClass('in-transit');
                   }

                }
              }
```

Here is the day difference method

```
function daysDifference(startDate,endDate){
         return  moment.duration({days: startDate.clone().stripTime().diff(endDate.clone().stripTime(), 'days')});
    }
```

Please see the issue here[image: Image in Week view]

[image: Issue coming in month view]

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this issue, hope it will help to others.

Previous code

```
day     = jsDate.getDate ();
```

Now

```
 day     = jsDate.getUTCDate ();
```